# Can somone please explain how this algebra works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When trying to solve for X, I saw the following.

Since we know that AX = B + CX, consequently X = B/(A - C).

I see this works in practice, but I don't understand what's happening. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Move the $CX$ term to the right hand side, give $X$ ans a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
AX &= B+CX\\
AX - CX &= B+CX-CX\\
AX-CX &= B\\
(A-C)X &=B\\
\frac{1}{A-C}\Bigl( (A-C)X\Bigr) &= \frac{1}{A-C}\Bigl(B\Bigr) &\quad\text{if }A-C\neq 0\\
\left(\frac{A-C}{A-C}\right)X &= \frac{B}{A-C} &\quad\text{if }A-C\neq 0\\
X &= \frac{B}{A-C} &\quad\text{if }A-C\neq 0.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for the fast and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start

$$AX = B + CX$$

Subtract $CX$ from both sides

$$AX -CX = B$$

Factor left-hand-side

$$(A -C)X = B$$

Divide both sides by $A-C$ if it is not zero

$$X = \frac{B}{A-C}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$AX=B+CX$$

Subtract $CX$ from both sides and divide by $A-C$

$$AX-CX=B$$

$$(A-C)X=B$$

$$ X=\frac {B}{A-C}$$